# Using Courier Imap to deliver Getmail Folder

Tags: linux, email, imap, courier

I am running ubuntu and I have a script that runs getmail and pulls mail from 10 different mailboxes by imap and places in a folder called ~/allmail.

I have then changed the maildir in courier to look in allmail/

Thinking that would be all I try to connect locally and cannot connect the logs are below. Any help would be great

> Apr 18 10:44:16 ks3298996 imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
>   Apr 18 10:44:31 ks3298996 imapd: chdir Maildir: No such file or directory
>   Apr 18 10:44:31 ks3298996 imapd: kurtis: No such file or directory

Comment: "No such file or directory" ... you sure did enter the correct path? If in doubt use an absolute path `~/allmail -> /home/user/allmail`.

Comment: it is 100% correct.

Comment: "I have then changed the maildir in courier to look in allmail/" - can you specify what exactly you did? Because the error message part `chdir Maildir: No such file or directory` implies that it's still looking for `./Maildir`.